# How to make the Pages in WordPress Customized?

Tags: customization, pages

I have a Theme I like. The front page is terrific. However, the pages have horrible formatting. How do I bypass this & get my own page formatting? (I know I have done this before...)

If possible, I would rather NOT change, edit, or delete code (or a .css file). I will do this as a last resort.

How do you get around the "blog-like" pages and create your own formatting? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the theme. Most themes provide a composer (like Visual Composer) to adjust page content. If your theme doesn't work with a composer, you have to change the server files. Take a look at the [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) workaround then.